# Pattern #1 field #2 has constraint conflicts which make the pattern

Tags: clips

I would like to make this rule

```
(defrule practica-superada1
    (or
        (and
            (oav ?alumno p1 apto)
            (oav ?alumno p2 apto)
        )
        (and
            (oav ?alumno p1|p2 apto)
            (oav ?alumno trabajo ok)
        )

    )
    =>
    (assert (oav ?alumno practica superada))
)
```

as this way:

```
(defrule practica-superada1
    (or
        (oav ?alumno p1&p2 apto)
        (and
            (oav ?alumno p1|p2 apto)
            (oav ?alumno trabajo ok)
        )

    )
    =>
    (assert (oav ?alumno practica superada))
)
```

The first way it's OK. But the second it's not. I receive the error:

`Pattern #1 field #2 has constraint conflicts which make the pattern`

Could someone explain me the cause of this error?

Answer (score 0):

The field constraint p1&p2 will only be matched if the value for that position in the fact is both p1 and p2. That can't happen. You can't replace two patterns that each need to match a separate fact with a single pattern.

Your original rule is in the simplest form you can write it, given that it's handling two different cases. You could reduce the fact conditional elements to just two, but then you'd have to include a complicated test conditional element:

```
(defrule practica-superada1
   (oav ?alumno ?v1 apto)
   (oav ?alumno ?v2 ?v3)
   (test (or (and (eq ?v1 p1)
                  (eq ?v2 p2)
                  (eq ?v3 apto))
             (and (or (eq ?v1 p1) (eq ?v1 p2))
                  (eq ?v2 trabajo)
                  (eq ?v3 ok))))
    =>
    (assert (oav ?alumno practica superada)))
```

Comment: Thanks, I get it. Then, the best way to get the same result it's the first version? It's any way for optimizing the rule not having to repeat (oav ?alumno p1 apto) (oav ?alumno p2 apto)... (oav ?alumno pn apto)?

Comment: That's correct. Your original rule is the simplest way to handle both cases.